# Java getBytes()

Tags: java

Do you know the problem as to why i am not getting Hello

```
byte f []  ="hello".getBytes();

System.out.println(f.toString());
```

Comment: FWIW, `System.out.write(f); System.out.flush();` should work roughly as expected. And probably something using `printf` too.

Answer (score 11):

Because `byte[]#toString()` is (usually) not implemented as `new String(byteArray)`, which would lead to the result you expect (e.g. `System.out.println(new String(byteArray));`.

You may want to give [this page](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t62802.html) an eye...

Answer (score 0):

Because the `toString` method of a byte array does not print its contents (at all). And bytes are not characters anyway. Why do you expect to see `"hello"`? Why not doing `System.out.println("hello")` directly?

Comment: I'd suppose he's trying to understand how java arrays work...?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting "strange" output from `System.out.println(f.toString())` is that you are printing an array, not a String.  Java's array classes *do not* override the `toString()` method.  Therefore the `toString()` method that is being called is the one from `java.lang.Object` which is defined to output the object's class name and its identity hashcode.  (In this case, the class name of the `byte[]` class will be "[b".)

I think your confusion arises from the fact that you are mentally equating a String and a byte array.  There are two reasons why this is conceptually wrong:

- In Java, Strings are not arrays of anything.  The String class a fully encapsulated class that cannot be cast to anything else .... apart from Object.
- In Java, a String models a sequence of characters, not a sequence of bytes.

The latter is a key difference because there are many possible conversions between character sequences and bytes, many of which are lossy in one or both directions.  When you call `"hello".getBytes()` you get the conversion implied by your platform's default character encoding, but you could have supplied a parameter to `getBytes` to use a different encoding in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

as `f` is not a `string`, `toString()` method of `object` class is called and not of `String` class.
`toString` of `String` class returns a `String` and `toString` of `object` class returns :

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`
..... aww aww dont go too far ...its same as :
`classname.@hexadecimal` code for the hash code

Answer (score -2):

You're not able to convert between a byte array and a String without providing an encoding method.

Try `System.out.println(new String(f, "UTF8"));`

Comment: Wrong! You *can* go from `byte[]` to String without specifying an encoding, just as you *can* go the other way without specifying an encoding. You **shouldn't** do either of those things, 'though.

Comment: @Joachim: Actually, you can't. Java uses a character model based on Unicode, and those do not correspond at all to bytes. All you can do is use a default conversion, but that's sucky. This whole mess is why `java.io.Reader` etc were added in Java 1.1.

Comment: @Donal: I know very well how Java handles characters (and their conversions to bytes). You **can** convert a `byte`-array to a String by using this constructor: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[]%29
It **will** use the "platform default charset" and that's most likely not what you want, but it's still possible.

Comment: Oh, I'm aware of the platform-default transformations, but they're not useful in that you can't in general take either an arbitrary byte sequence or an arbitrary character sequence, transform it to the other and back, and guarantee to get back what you started with. Both directions can lose information, depending on what the system default encoding is. (It pays to be careful; use UTF-8 if you're starting from characters, and one of the ISO8859 encodings if you're starting from bytes.)

Comment: @Donal: of course it has troubles, that's what I mean with "you shouldn't do [it]" in my initial comment. But "it is problematic" is **not** the same as "you can't do it". And trying to convert arbitrary binary data to character data is dangerous, no matter which encoding you use (excluding BASE64 and other encodings which are not really character encodings).